# Add JFace TableViewer to SWT Table

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

In a tool, I'm working on, I have a table, that I add like so:

```
public void addTable() {

    table = new Table(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    griddata = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    griddata.horizontalSpan = 2;

    table.setLayoutData(griddata);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    final TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    final TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
    final TableColumn tc3 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);

    tc1.setText("ID");
    tc2.setText("Firstname");
    tc3.setText("Lastname");

    tc1.setWidth(30);
    tc2.setWidth(100);
    tc3.setWidth(100);

    final TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText(new String[] { "ABC", "Hatton", "Kentucky" });
    final TableItem item2 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item2.setText(new String[] { "DEF", "Warner", "Ohio" });
}
```

Works well, but now, I'd like to add a JFace table viewer, but the documentation on that seems to concern with TableLayouts only, not Tables. I thought, the TableViewer would be added onto of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the meantime. It's just a change in the first to lines, like so:

```
        TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION); 
    table = viewer.getTable();
```

That way, you can contract the table like before.